# Accessing ViewSet object list to provide extra context to serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am attempting to add context to a serializer within a `ModelViewSet` which is dependent on the current paged object list in context. I'll explain with an example.

I am building a `viewsets.ModelViewSet` that lists `User`s and a list of `favorite_foods`. However- the list of user's favorite foods in some external microservice accessible via API. Building a ViewSet to collect objects and performing HTTP requests on each is trivial, we can do something like this:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     favorite_foods = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

     def get_favorite_foods(self, instance):
         # performs an HTTP call and returns a list[] of foods. 
         return evil_coupled_microservice_client.get_user_food_list(instance)
    
     class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'favorite_foods')
```

The issue is (aside from some ugly infrastructure coupling) this is going to make an HTTP request count equivalent to the page size. Instead- it would be great if I could prefetch the favorite food lists for all users on the page in a single HTTP call, and just add them into context, like this:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def get_serializer_context(self): 
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        users = <-- This is where I want to know what users are in the current filtered, paginated response. 
        users_food_dict = evil_coupled_microservice_client.get_many_users_food_list(users)
        context.update({'usesr_foods': users_food_dict})
        return context
```

However- it doesn't appear there is any way to fetch the object list that's going to be serialized. Although (I'm fairly sure) `get_serializer_context` is called after the queryset is filtered and paginated, I'm not sure how to access it without doing some really hacking re-compiling of the queryset based on the query_params and other pieces attached to the class.

Comment: you can override `list()` and update the serializer's context there

Comment: Yeah- I'm working on my own answer to this in which I do that, but this feels like a relatively common issue, and django usually has some magic built in for those.

Comment: I have the same thoughts before but after searching and reading the source code there was no other place to go.

Comment: If you take a look there you will get the same feeling too https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/8812394ed83d7cce0ed5b2c5fcf093269d364b9b/rest_framework/mixins.py#L33

Comment: everything is decoupled, so when we need something like this which is dependent on the filtered data we are forced to go where everything is set together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post my current solution. It's not terrible, but I'm still hoping for a cleaner built-in.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet): 
    ...
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Overrwite `ListModelMixin` and store current set
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            self.current_queryset = page
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        self.current_queryset = queryset
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This is untested so far (not sure about functionality on Detail endpoints for instance) allows for the `current_queryset` to be fetched within the serializer context.